# Laravel method declaration

Tags: laravel

I am learning Laravel and from time to time I want to see the "source code" of various methods it uses. Example:

[image]

I understand that "->authorize('update', $chirp)" is a method declared somewhere in Laravel files. When I right click on "authorize":

[image]

and then click "Goto Defenition":

[image]

I see numerous possible sources to choose from. I have to "guess" where to look then and in many cases just give up after browsing numerous files...
What is your routine for finding the actual declarations of such methods?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a method, it will be defined in the class of the object or an ancestor. If the IDE isn't filtering out non-ancestors, you'll have to check the type of the object, and then look to its ancestors. With `$this`, that will be the class currently being defined.

Comment: Or it could be one of the classes that your current class extends. Sometimes you have to go a few levels to find it.

Comment: @aynber: correct, the ancestors.